# how to make the space between column 1 and 2 the same

Tags: python, unix, text, file-handling

I am at the moment trying to filter a lexicon/dictionary such that it only contains the word i need. The dictionary has two column first being the word, and the second being the phonetic pronunciation (see the image below).

[image: Snippet of lexicon]

The lexicon is available [here](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/sphinxdict/cmudict.0.7a_SPHINX_40).

Is there some way I can make this space/delimiter even for all the cases...  It would make things a lot more easier.

Comment: This space is a tab, so you can easly do`for line in file: values = line.split('\t')`, and then access words with `values[0]` and phonetical with `values[1]`

Comment: oh.. I feel stupid. It solved my issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like the following?
[here](http://pastebin.com/qvyEmbUr)

In this case, this is the code (without using any particular characters):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys

path_to_the_file = sys.argv[1]

word = []
pron = []
maxword = 0
with open(path_to_the_file) as fr:
    for line in fr:
        words = line.split()
        word.append(words[0])
        pron.append(' '.join(words[1:]))
        if len(words[0]) > maxword: maxword = len(words[0])

format_str = '{:'+str(maxword)+'s}  {:s}\n'

msg = ''
for w,p in zip(word,pron):
    msg += format_str.format(w,p)

print msg
```